# neovim: exit code for jobs terminated by jobstop

Tags: neovim, job-control

When I call `jobstop` on a running script waiting for input, the `on_exit` callback is invoked. But the exit code is always 0.
Is this the correct behavior?

According to `:h jobstop` it should be killed by `SIGTERM`.

> jobstop({id})                     *jobstop()*
>         Stop |job-id| {id} by sending SIGTERM to the job process. If
>         the process does not terminate after a timeout then SIGKILL
>         will be sent. When the job terminates its |on_exit| handler
>         (if any) will be invoked.

Shouldn't it have some nonzero exit code?